# Unable to get desired output using UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, sax, rss-reader

I am trying to parse an RSS XML URL and it contains language other than English. I used UTF-8 encoding to get the desired output but same result

below is the code :

```
    InputStream in = new URL(rssUrl).openStream();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8");
    InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
    is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    T handler = null;
    handler=handlerClass.newInstance();
    saxParser.parse(is, handler);
    return handler.getRssItemList();
```

I am still getting out of various tags like "????? ??? ????" 
Thanks in advance

Handler code:

```
       if (isTitle) {
            title = new String(ch, start, length);
            String result=null;
            currentItem.setTitle(title);
        }
```

not doing any UTF-8 stuff in handler code , just normal way

Comment: Perhaps the problem is how you're outputting the strings rather than their content? Have you looked at the numeric values of the UTF-16 code units in the strings?

Comment: Or perhaps the problem is that you're getting those `????` because that's what is actually being sent, if the source is not encoding the characters properly before sending them out to you. Have you invoked `rssUrl` manually with a browser to check what is being returned?

Comment: i am getting value of some character like this "2351" when i fetch it as an integer

Comment: @walen .. yes i have invoked it ... it is returning the desired content ..the XML is like this `<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0">`

Comment: Can you please indicate us the rss source or a sample of it, and also please show what you are doing in your `ContentHandler`.

Comment: https://www.gazabpost.com/rss/category/entertainment ... this is the xml RSS Url .. and i have edited the question for handler